# Flutter: SVG <image> preserveAspectRatio not working

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I have an SVG string that looks like this

```
<g transform="translate(0,-37.01)" id="g73">
   <rect style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0" x="-156.06" y="-156.06" rx="22.700001" ry="22.700001" width="312.12" height="312.12" id="rect71"/>
</g>
<image width="295.91602" height="295.91599" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="$_profileImage" id="image21342" x="-148.14604" y="-185.1489" style="stroke-width:0;stroke-dasharray:none;paint-order:markers stroke fill"/>
```

I want the image to be stretched depending on its size but  `preserveAspectRatio="none"` is not working it looks like the picture below.

[image]

It should be like this.

[image]

Comment: The one in the middle, the rect is the white white background

Comment: The image itself has a white border on the sides, you'll need to edit the image to remove it.

Comment: That's not my problem actually, my problem is the stretching of image tag, I need the image to be square even if it's portrait.

Comment: You can set `SvgPicture.asset(...fit: BoxFit.cover,)`  or `BoxFit.fill` which is you need..